# how to finish parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

i am new to android..

Version [2.2]

i have created a main activity[A], on clicking a button it goes to another activity[B](***"this  activity has transparent background so main activity[A] can also view" needed compulsory***).

Once i click back button from activity[B] it should go to activity[A] (or) activity[B] have some buttons, if i click any button from activity[B] it should go to activity[C].

From activity[C] it click back button activity[A] is live.

***For me, while click back button from activity[C] my app should be finish()......***

plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your **activity[c]** put this code-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity[c].class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                            startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in your `onCreate` method of **activity[c]** put this code-

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the intent use this code to kill the previous activities

```
Intent i=new Intent(activity[a].this,activity[b].class);
startActivity(i);
activity[a].this.finish();
```

this code help clear the all activity example:its clear activity[a] and activity[b]

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity[c].this,activity[a].class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

when your activity A is created, you must create an instance of Activity A.
For eg. 
    static A instanceA=this;
now create a static method getInstace()

```
public static A getInstance(){
       return   instanceA;
     }
enter code here

Now in Activity B on setonclicklistener 
write A.getInstance().finish(); //For Activity A
```

And also finish() //For Activity B

Answer (score 0):

Hi Do the following changes one by one. To Achieve this every Activity Should be started with startActivityForResult instead startActivity.

1. While Starting Acitivity A to B you Should use the below Code.

   startActivityForResult(new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class),12);
2. While Starting Acitivity B to c you Should use the below Code.

   startActivityForResult(new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class),12);

Add the below method in All Three Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      
        if(resultCode==12){
              setResult(12);    
              this.finish();
        }
}
```

Add the Code when you finishing any Activity. ( If you click finish button in Activity A or B or C) then add below the onClick of Button Finish).

```
setResult(12);
ClassName.this.finish();
```

dont use onBackPressed and startActivity. Its an easy way to Handle this.